# formula for conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Need your help on below scenario.

There are three conditions. if A Column contain more than 5 and B column contain more than 5...then c column has to be show as "YES". if any of A and B column contain below than 5...then C column has to be show as "No".

So i have written formula like this =IF(AND(U9>0.05,W9>0.05),"Yes","No"). It was working.

But i need one more condition has to be added here. if A column contain blank..and B column contain any value...the C column has to be show as blank.

Please help anybody on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this amended version

=IF(U9="","",IF(AND(U9>0.05,W9>0.05),"Yes","No"))

Answer (score 1):

I would think:

**=IF(AND(U9="", W9<>""), "", IF(AND(U9>0.05, W9>0.05), "Yes", "No")))**

Comment: The best "thanks" is for you to click the UP ARROW to vote the answer you find most usable and signal this thread is solved.